# Compare two vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, programming-languages, octave

I think, the question might have already been asked before. But I could not find proper answer in this forum.

Acutally, I have 2 vectors( of unequal length). I need to compare the 2 vectors. I can do it using a for loop. But it is taking a very  long time.

Any obvious method which I may be missising ?

here is a small code snippet:

```
a=[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4];
b=[ 2 3 4];
```

How can we compare a and b. Basically I need the index in vector a when comparison returns true.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for the index in a for where b is a subsequence of a?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for index in a, where b is a subsequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`strfind()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strfind.html) for this (it works with doubles):

```
idx = strfind(a, b);
```

`idx` will contain the indices of all matches.